# How do I hard wire new oven to existing wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, oven

I need to connect new replacement GE double wall oven wires to house wires where old oven wires were connected.  Existing house wires are:  black, red, white, and 
bare copper.  New oven has black, red, and  the white/copper wires are clamped together.  How do I connect the oven white/copper clamped wires with the house white and copper wires?  Power is off at box.  Verified wires from house are dead.  Thank you!

Comment: Check the installation instructions, or give us the exact model number.  It likely tells you to remove the clamp for 4-wire installs.

Comment: It is GE # JT5500.

Comment: It does say to remove the clamp.  I tried that but it was really tight so I thought I'd ask before I damaged it!

Comment: Remove it like they say.

Comment: Okay, so then it is just the 4 wires attaching to the existing 4 wires?  That makes sense.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  Really old houses may only have 3-wires which is why the do this. 4-wire install are better and safer tho.

Comment: Really appreciate your help with this!  I'm teaching myself slowly.  Thanks again, Tyson.

Comment: @Pamela -- is the junction box metal or plastic?

Answer (score 1):

### Remove the clamp -- cut off the clamped end and restrip the neutral if you have to

If the clamp is too tight, you may have to cut off the clamp and then strip the insulation from the cut end of the neutral.  This is mentioned in step 8A of the install instructions for your oven:

> Free the neutral (white) lead from being restrained to any other
>   wires. If necessary, cut the neutral (white) lead and then re-strip
>   it to expose the proper length of conductor.

From there, it's a matter of attaching like to like with the wirenuts -- red goes to red, black to black, white to white, and bare to bare + the box ground pigtail (bare or green) if there is one.  If there isn't a box ground pigtail and the box is made from metal -- get a bag of 'em and screw the screw-end into the screw-hole in the box, then nut the wire-end in with the bare wires.

Comment: So instead of using the twist caps, I'd secure all of the wires together under a pigtail on the metal box?

Comment: @Pamela -- the pigtail from the box (which'll be bare or green) needs to go into the twist-cap that has the bare wires from the oven and house going into it

Comment: I was confused about what a pigtail was.  The pigtail is the bare wire coming from the house?

Comment: I wiuld add red and black are both hots, and are interchangeable.   They are color coded differently *in standard cable* because sometimes the difference matters... here, it does not.

Comment: @Pamela -- the pigtail is the bare or green wire coming from a screw *on the box itself*

Comment: @Pamela -- your box is metal, right? Also, can you take a photo of its innards and share it with us?